# SQL server update with 2 left joins and a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update products in my 'products' table that are not present in 2 other tables. The products have a unique identifier 'ean'. My plan was to do 2 left joins with the other tables and then update if both other ean fields contained null. Using MS SQL Server by the way.

Tables: product, table2, table3

```
  update product 
  set published = 0
  from p as product
   left join a as table2
     on p.ean = a.ean
   left join t as table3
     on p.ean = t.ean
  where t.ean is null and a.ean is null
```

Since it doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is wrong? any error or wrong data? You should test first with `SELECT` without `UPDATE` to make sure the query is returning the correct rows

Comment: your where clause may need the declared names (table3.ean ). we may be able to help more if we see the sample data involved in this scenario

Comment: I think you put the alias backwards. If the table name is `table2` then you should write `LEFT JOIN table2 as A`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your alias.

If your tables are `product, table2, table3` then your query should be:

```
update P
set published = 0
from product as P
left join table2 as A
  on P.ean = A.ean
left join table3 as T 
  on P.ean = T.ean
where T.ean is null and A.ean is null
```